# UI Dispatcher message queue becomes full

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher, postmessage

I launch a long running task(T1) as a process from UI thread and wait for its completion. T1 exits only if user manually closes. If user does not close that task then the UI thread keep waiting in the while loop. After 10-15 hours the main program exits with the exception given below. According to my understanding this is happening because the UI Dispatcher is busy in `process.WaitForExit(300000)`, so it is not able to process the message queue and queue becomes full after a considerable amount of time. I want to ask how we can clear the UI dispatcher message queue so that it does not throw an exception when left running for long time.

I know that this is not a good practice of launching long running tasks on UI thread, we can use Background Worker.

UI thread in WPF application

```
            // Stop the process from opening a new window
            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            // Setup executable and parameters
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "Some .exe path";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;


            if (false == process.Start())
            {
                return false;
            }

            while (!process.WaitForExit(300000))
            {
                // here I want to Process Dispather queue tasks if any present so that the queue does not become full
            }`
```

The exception which gets generated:

```
Exception Info: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
Stack:
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.PostMessage(System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef, MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.UpdateWindowSettings(Boolean, System.Nullable`1)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.UpdateWindowPos(IntPtr)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.HandleMessage(MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.HwndTargetFilterMessage(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.WaitHelper(IntPtr[], Boolean, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherSynchronizationContext.Wait(IntPtr[], Boolean, Int32)
   at System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.InvokeWaitMethodHelper(System.Threading.SynchronizationContext, IntPtr[], Boolean, Int32)
   at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle, UInt32, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle, Int64, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(Int32, Boolean)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.WaitForExit(Int32)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `await Dispatcher.Yield(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle)`
According to Docs: Creates an awaitable object that asynchronously yields control back to the 
current dispatcher and provides an opportunity for the dispatcher to process other events

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `process.Exited` event instead, so it does not block?

Comment: I want to wait till the process gets completed. All further action is dependent  on the process exitcode and other such values.

Comment: Why can't you do further actions in the event handler code? Do you need to return a code to the caller? Could a callback handle that?